# How do I call a method recursively?

Tags: java, inheritance, recursion, methods

I'm trying to recursively call a method until I obtain the desired output. However, I want to call a method from another class and get information from that method in order to use it in my recursive method. For example, suppose I have a parent class called `Cake` that contains information about a cake such as its batter(i.e. amount the batter), an extended class with a specific type of cake containing a unique  instance of the batter, and I have another class called `Bakery` where I want to actually make cakes that are being ordered. I have a method in `Bakery` called `createCake`, and I want to recursively call this method until enough batter is in the pan to create a cake. If the amount of batter is randomly generated in the extended class, how do I call the `getBatter` method from that class and capture the information about the batter amount in order to use it in my recursive method for creating the cakes? Can anyone help me out with this? I'm doing something similar to this, but I don't quite understand how I would go about actually getting the information in order to get the recursion to work. I have an example of the code below, so that you can have an idea of what I'm trying to do (I know it's not very accurate). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;

public abstract class Cake
{
   static Random gen = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

   public int type; //type of cake
   public static int batter = gen.nextInt() * 3; //random amount of batter

   public int getType()
   {
     return type;
   }

   public int getBatter()
   {
      return batter;
   }
}


public class RedVelvet extends Cake
{
  public int type;
  public int batter = gen.nextInt(3)+6; //generates between 6-8 cups of batter inclusive

  public int getType()
  {
    return 1;
  }
  public int getBatter()
  {
    return batter;
  }
}

public class Chocolate extends Cake
{
  public int type;
  public int batter = gen.nextInt(3)+6; //generates between 6-8 cups of batter inclusive

  public int getType()
  {
    return 2;
  }
  public int getBatter()
  {
    return batter;
  }
}


public class Pound extends Cake
{
  public int type;
  public int batter = gen.nextInt(3)+6; 

  public int getType()
  {
    return 3;
  }
  public int getBatter()
  {
    return batter;
  }
}

public class Bakery
{
  import java.util.Scanner;
  System.out.print("Enter desired size of cake to be baked (Must be at least 12):");
  desiredSize=scan.nextInt();

  public static void createCake(int desiredSize, int currentSize) //currentSize is the current amount of batter in the pan
  {
    if (currentSize == desiredSize)
      return;
   else if (currentSize < desiredSize)
   {
     //Recursively call createCake method so that batter continues to be added to the pan until there is enough to make the desired cake size. I want to get the batter information from one of the extended classes in order to add it to the cake.
   }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear , please post some code i.e classes which you have created

Answer (score 0):

Is this for school or a course of sorts because I personally wouldn't go this route but then again that's my opinion. It's like, what the heck do I know about baking and I can safely tell you....absolutely nothing. Some may even say that about my programming/coding skills but then again, I'm not a programmer and I am self taught in almost all programming environments including good old Assembly most of which I have now forgotten. :/

I should think that when it comes to baking cakes (or most things for that matter) some sort of accuracy must be established so as to avoid waste and we all know that waste costs money. I'm not overly convinced that generating random amounts of cake batter is accurate enough for what you're most likely are trying to accomplish but then again, you already know this. I noticed that in your different cake classes they all basically generate a random number from 6 to 8. If they all do the same thing then why have them?

I don't believe you need recursion at all but instead a simple method called from within a loop, for example:

```
while (currentSize < desiredSize) {
    currentSize+= getBatter(cake, desiredSize);
}
```

Here is how I would do this and I apologize now if you find this is all totally meaningless:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bakery {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getBaking();  // :)

    }


    private static void getBaking(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 

        String cakeType = "";
        while (cakeType.equals("")) {
            System.out.print("Enter desired cake to be baked (Pound, Chocolate, "
                    + "RedVelvet) or\nenter 'exit' to quit: -> ");
            cakeType = scan.nextLine();
            if (cakeType.isEmpty()) { 
                System.out.println("\nYou must supply the name of cake to bake or "
                        + "enter 'exit' to quit!\n"); 
            }
            else if (cakeType.toLowerCase().equals("exit")) { System.exit(0); }
            else if (!cakeType.toLowerCase().matches("(pound|chocolate|redvelvet)")) {
                System.out.println("\nYou must supply the name of cake as shown above!\n");
                cakeType = "";
            } 

        }

        int desiredSize = 0;
        String size = "";
        while (size.equals("")) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter desired size of cake to be baked (must be at "
                    + "least 12\"): -> ");
            size = scan.nextLine();
            if (size.isEmpty()) { 
                System.out.println("\nYou must supply the size of cake to bake or "
                        + "enter 'exit' to quit!\n"); 
            }
            else if (size.toLowerCase().equals("exit")) { System.exit(0); }
            else if (Integer.valueOf(size.replace("\"","")) < 12 ) {
                System.out.println("\nYou must supply a cake size of 12\" or greater!\n");
                size = "";
            } 
        }
        desiredSize = Integer.valueOf(size.replace("\"",""));

        createCake(cakeType, desiredSize, 0);
    }

    public static void createCake(String cake, int desiredSize, int currentSize) {
        //currentSize is the current amount of batter in the pan
        while (currentSize < desiredSize) {
            currentSize+= getBatter(cake, desiredSize);
            System.out.println(currentSize);
        }

        System.exit(0); // Done! - Quit!
    } 

    public static int getBatter(String cake, int desiredSize) {
        Random gen = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Since the random generation for the batter amount is the
        // same for all cake types according to your code we just 
        // need this:
        int batterAmount = gen.nextInt(3)+6;

        // But if we want to be more specific for each Cake Type
        // then we can do it this way but first create the required 
        // batter equations for each cake type and remove the /* and 
        // */ from the code but first comment out (//) the batterAmount
        // variable declaration above.
        // NOTE: Both cake diameter AND 'Height' should play into the factor
        // of how much batter is required unless of course all cakes made are
        // of the same height.
        /*
        int batterAmount = 0;
        switch (cake.toLowerCase()) {
            case "pound":
                batterAmount = //batter amount to make 12 inch cake + (this much batter for a 1 inch cake * (desiredSize - 12));
                break;
            case "chocolate":
                batterAmount = //batter amount to make 12 inch cake + (this much batter for a 1 inch cake * (desiredSize - 12));
                break;
            case "redvelvet":
                batterAmount = //batter amount to make 12 inch cake + (this much batter for a 1 inch cake * (desiredSize - 12));
                break;
        } */

        return batterAmount;
    }   
}
```

Well, I do hope this has helped you somewhat or at least thrown a little thought into the oven :P

Comment: @DevilHnd Hi, I think that a while loop would be a better solution for this too, but I have to use recursion. I'm just not sure how to go about it, so I just came up with a similar problem to the one I'm working on. Thanks for your help though :) !